# How to group by year with the year showing only once

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I have tried using the following query

```
select distinct Year (SaleDate) AS SaleYear,Max(SalePrice)
from Sale
group by SaleDate
```

The years 2010 and 2014 are showing twice,even though i used distinct and group by. the amounts in Maxprice are different as well. am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Sometimes images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. More [insights here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Use this tool to generate [ASCII tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Hope this helps.

Comment: This might sound pedantic, but you're not getting true duplicates. The query is returning exactly what you're asking for. You're putting records into groups where they share the same `SalesMan` name and the same `YEAR(S.SaleDate)`. You are getting multiple results because multiple sales people have sales in a given year. If you only want one result per year, you have to add code to choose a single record, either based on the sales amount, count, or some other criterion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat `year()` in the `group by`:

```
select Year(SaleDate) AS SaleYear, Max(SalePrice)
from Sale
group by year(SaleDate);
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` is almost never correct.  All that your query does is aggregate by `SaleDate` and *in the result set* extract the year.  That is why you see duplicates.

Comment: I edited my original post after trying to do another select. Hopefully you can help with that.